# Why my Wordpress website homepage automatically adding cs_preview=true query parameter to the url?

Tags: urls

I took a help from freelancer to build a Wordpress website. Now whenever I go to the homepage at `<website-name>.com` it automatically redirects to `<website-name>.com/cs_preview=true`. I checked the dashboard and the permalink of the homepage is without this query parameter. How to remove this so that it looks more professional?

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without more information, WP doesn't add URL parameters like that, so it will be a library theme or plugin doing it

Comment: This is redirect. First of all, look at your .htaccess file in website folder.
(if you not understand anything, just try to use default) and ofcourse clean your browser cache.

Comment: Are you using https://wordpress.org/plugins/coming-soon/ ?